# How can I obtain/generate a pair of fonts differring only on ascenders?

Tags: fonts, alignment, font-design, libre-office

I'm doing some QA work on the [LibreOffice](https://libreoffice.org/) free software office suite w.r.t. vertical alignment behavior in some scenarios.

To illustrate a point, and perhaps to test a theory, I need to use two fonts which are identical, or very close to identical, and specifically with the same basic metrics (median, x-height etc.) - except that one of them has longer ascenders. I don't care much about aesthetics, I just need an extended b, l, d etc.

Now, I'm not a font-smith and have no experience with font editing programs (although in a pinch I might even do that). What's an easy way for me to obtain or two generate such a pair of fonts?